# Inheriting Bash signal traps

Tags: bash, signals

I'm struggling to find clear, unambiguous information about how the `trap` command works.

In particular, is the effect of `trap` local to the script where it appears? I had always assumed this to be the case, but I've seen statements to the contrary. Does `trap` affect other shell scripts called from the current one? Does it affect binary programs?

Comment: Docs on trap cmd: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html. I'd also go through this tutorial if you're confused about how it works: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-usingtraps/. Excellent details and covers child procs.

Comment: Good question. Not sure if you have figured it out. I also have similiar confusions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387038/how-can-i-determine-the-traps-inherited-from-a-shell-to-a-command-executable-or

Answer (score 4):

You can test it out quickly enough:

```
$ cat test.sh
trap : INT HUP USR1
sleep 10h
$ ./test.sh &
[1] 29668
$ grep SigCgt /proc/$(pgrep test.sh)/status
SigCgt: 0000000000010203
$ grep SigCgt /proc/$(pgrep sleep)/status
SigCgt: 0000000000000000
```

So `trap` doesn't affect binaries.

What about scripts?

```
$ cat blah.sh 
#! /bin/bash    
grep SigCgt /proc/$$/status
$ cat test.sh 
#! /bin/bash
trap : INT HUP USR1
./blah.sh
$ ./test.sh 
SigCgt: 0000000000010002
```

So something's being caught. But wait!

```
$ ./blah.sh 
SigCgt: 0000000000010002
```

Looks like those signals are handled anyway.

---

The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash) has this to say:

```
   When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is  to  be
   executed,  it  is  invoked  in  a  separate  execution environment that
   consists of the following.  Unless  otherwise  noted,  the  values  are
   inherited from the shell.
   ...
   ·      traps caught by the shell are reset to the values inherited from
          the shell's parent, and traps ignored by the shell are ignored
```

---

If you want to convert that bitmask to a set of signals, try:

```
HANDLED_SIGS=$(awk '/SigCgt/{print "0x"$2}' /proc/$PID/status)
for i in {0..31} 
do 
    (( (1 << i) & $HANDLED_SIGS )) && echo $((++i)) $(/bin/kill --list=$i); 
done | column
```

In this case, the set of signals that were handled without `trap` were:

```
$ HANDLED_SIGS=0x0000000000010002
$ for i in {0..31}; do (( (1 << i) & $HANDLED_SIGS )) && echo $((++i)) $(/bin/kill --list=$i); done | column
2 INT   17 CHLD
```

Comment: I tried `grep /proc/$$/status` after various combinations of `trap`. I seem to get `SigCgt: 43817efb` in all cases. What the heck...?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Looks like you ran that grep in an interactive shell, which already traps a variety of signals.

Comment: Nope. It's running from a script file, that successively turns on various traps and prints out the result after each one.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Can you post the script? (at, say, http://paste.ubuntu.com or a Github gist)

Comment: See my other "answer".

Comment: Coming back to my original question, your answer appears to basically say "yes, `trap` is local to one script file". Is that right?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid except for signals which are ignored, yes.

Comment: How does one "ignore" a signal? You mean `trap - SIGINT` permanently disables that signal for all child processes?

Comment: `trap -` resets it. You use the null string for ignoring: `trap '' SIGINT`, and not permanently, but by default. The child process can choose to catch it, if it wants.

Comment: Did you actually try to SIG the sleep and see what happens? I have a BusyBox here, which shows SigCgt 0 for a child (crond - binary) of a dead parent (cron restart - script) which has had a kill trap. The parent is still blocking any attempt to kill its child. That means, at least on this sytem, binary did inherit the trap, still has it after parent died, and not showing it in SigCgt.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but...

```
$ cat Trap.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Trap.sh is PID $$"
trap -p
grep Sig /proc/$$/status

trap 'echo SIGINT' SIGINT
trap -p
grep Sig /proc/$$/status

trap 'echo SIGTERM' SIGTERM
trap -p
grep Sig /proc/$$/status

trap 'echo SIGUSR1' SIGUSR1
trap -p
grep Sig /proc/$$/status

$ ./Trap.sh
Trap.sh is PID 13887
SigQ:   0/63517
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000010000
SigIgn: 0000000000000004
SigCgt: 0000000043817efb
trap -- 'echo SIGINT' SIGINT
SigQ:   0/63517
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000010000
SigIgn: 0000000000000004
SigCgt: 0000000043817efb
trap -- 'echo SIGINT' SIGINT
trap -- 'echo SIGTERM' SIGTERM
SigQ:   0/63517
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000010000
SigIgn: 0000000000000004
SigCgt: 0000000043817efb
trap -- 'echo SIGINT' SIGINT
trap -- 'echo SIGUSR1' SIGUSR1
trap -- 'echo SIGTERM' SIGTERM
SigQ:   0/63517
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000010000
SigIgn: 0000000000000004
SigCgt: 0000000043817efb
```

I have no idea what this means. My *guess* is that Bash is trapping everything, and then deciding what to do inside the trap routine.

Comment: I think you should add this to the question. And apparently it's set to 0x43817efb only after the `trap -p` (if you remove that, or shift it to after the `grep`, you get the correct value). Dunno why.

Comment: How odd... I have no idea why it would do that.